# Is it possible to make a method that takes any number of arguments?

Tags: java

I was looking at another post here which was **describing** what seems to be **my** **problem**:
[How to make a method which accepts any number of arguments of any type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354333/how-to-make-a-method-which-accepts-any-number-of-arguments-of-any-type-in-java)

**However**, when I attempted to do this method, when I **compiled** the program it gave me the **error** *"int cannot be converted to java.util.Objects"*

What am I doing wrong?

### Code:

```
public static void clearArray (Objects... args)
{
    System.out.println("Error, non character value");
}
```

### How I called the function:

```
import java.util.Objects;
// Stuff...
clearArray(1);
// Other stuff...
```

Thank you for checking out my problem!

Comment: Thanks for the effort but you do not need to edit you question to put the answer. Best way to reward the best answer is to accept and upvote it. :) Good luck with that code

Comment: Alright :). Thanks, it did what it was suppose to do which is always a reward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `java.lang.Object`, not `java.util.Objects`.

`java.util.Objects` is a class with utility methods, not a class you can actually extend and instantiate.

`java.lang.Object` on the other hand is the superclass of all objects in Java.

And even in a multi-param (varargs) method, the signature needs to be `Object ...`, not `Objects ...`.

Comment: @RileyCarney no prob. Most of us have done worse :-)

Answer (score 7):

Look at the signature

```
public static void clearArray (Objects... args)
```

That method receivng Objects type and you are passing integer to it. Perhaps changing that to

```
public static void clearArray (Object... args)
```

Helps.